# Where to place my R scripts in serv/shiny-server

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have uploaded my app scripts into srv/shiny-server as dashboard_test. But i am not able to run it. While looking into the error log I am receiving this.

Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.

Also One thing I noticed, the scripts for sample app is placed on opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps/hello. I tried putting there but i don't have the permission for that.Do i need to put them there as well? while,
I am following this article where it says "Any Shiny app directory that you place under /srv/shiny-server/ will be served as a Shiny app " it should work. https://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/#user-libraries

I am trying to understand what is going wrong.
[Please find the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxyZp.png)

Comment: Are there any logs? Look under `/var/log/shiny-server/` for logs to indicate whatever console warnings/errors you might have to give you a hint where to go. (When this behavior happened to me, it was because I had an error in my script that worked fine in my local R but was missing some path changes under shiny server.)

Comment: yep! The error log is showing as" Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization" I am wondering if I have to put it under 
   opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps/  ???

Comment: Okay, I was hoping for something R-specific (as in "there is no package called ..."). Huh, sorry, that's most of what I had. I don't think putting it under /samples/ makes sense ... to me, `/srv/shiny-server/dashboard_test/` make sense. Are you [running it as the `shiny` user?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/Vh6lgbk4n9k). Other related: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/issues/353, https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/issues/323